# How to keep image the same size on HTML when image changes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to include two images in my webpage. One image stays the same, the other one will change, and it will change to images that has a different aspect ratio.

I want the image that will change to always be the same height as the first image (the one that doesn't change). When I change the image to another image with a different aspect ratio then the images are no longer the same height.

I've tried using `overflow:hidden` as I thought it would just crop out the overflowing areas of the image. I looked into using `flex` but as the aspect ratio keeps changing I didn't think it would be appropriate.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img id="img1" src="https://cdn.silodrome.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/iPhone-5.jpg">
            <img id="img2" src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--6tZPLps6--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/trrsg0bnoouitdhsoe0s.jpg"
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And this is my CSS:**

```
html {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0pc;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

#img1 {
  width: 20%;
}

#img2 {
  width: 78.5%;
}
```

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKqwMr) to demonstrate the issue.

I want to be able to change `img2` to any image and it have the same height. I would also like it to always be in the center of the space for the second image but I'm sure that is something I can work out.

Comment: Since the first image does not change, you can apply the first image's height to dynamically changing image. Also don't apply width to the dynamic image. Now the dynamic image will resize to exact height of the first one and width will adjust automatically keeping the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I have given a fixed height to the height of the div and added some properties in #img1 and #img2. Hope it will be helpful to you.

```css
html {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0pc;
}
div {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 25vw;
}
#img1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-positon: center center;
}
#img2 {
  width: 78.5%;
  height: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-positon: center center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img id="img1" src="https://cdn.silodrome.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/iPhone-5.jpg">
      <img id="img2" src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--6tZPLps6--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/trrsg0bnoouitdhsoe0s.jpg"
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was after!

Comment: Thank you @Dritz . Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your css to this

```
#img1 {
  height: 400px; /* This value can be whatever */
}
#img2 {
  height: 400px; /* This value can be whatever */
}
```

this will keep the aspect ratio of the images and apply a fixed height to both of them. It's recommended to use pixels and not a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width and height of the `<img>` to a fix value

```
<img src="example.gif" alt="Example" width="200" height="100">
```

Comment: Is is not possible using percentages? I wanted the images to be able to be scaled with the browser

Comment: You can use px or percentage in the width and height attribute: http://www.tagindex.net/html/img/img_width.html